# hide or display forms in ms access

Tags: ms-access

I have a tabbed form and would like the user to select two options from two different option groups namely Type and Ownership which are on the same form. If the two selected options in the Option Groups meet a condition, then only one tabbed form should display.
I have shown my code below which does not function properly.
Please advise what could be wrong or is there an alternative code.
Code:

```
Private Sub Ownership_AfterUpdate()
If Me.Type.Value = 1 And Me.Ownership = 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 6 Then
Me.HousesToRent.Visible = True
Me.HousesForSale.Visible = False
Me.ApartmentToRent.Visible = False
Me.ApartmentForSale.Visible = False
Me.OfficeAndWarehouse.Visible = False
Me.PlotForSale.Visible = False
End If
If Me.Type.Value = 3 And Me.Ownership = 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 6 Then
Me.HousesToRent.Visible = False
Me.HousesForSale.Visible = True
Me.ApartmentToRent.Visible = False
Me.ApartmentForSale.Visible = False
Me.OfficeAndWarehouse.Visible = False
Me.PlotForSale.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks it works but I have a combinations of options as below: Private Sub Ownership_AfterUpdate()
If Me.Type.Value = 1 And Me.Ownership = 1 Then
Me.HousesToRent.Visible = False
Me.HousesForSale.Visible = False
Me.ApartmentToRent.Visible = True
Me.ApartmentForSale.Visible = False
Me.OfficeAndWarehouse.Visible = False
Me.PlotForSale.Visible = False
End If
If Me.Type.Value = 3 And Me.Ownership = 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 6 Then ..............
End Sub. So how can I include this on in addition to you first answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is not complete:

```
Private Sub Ownership_AfterUpdate()

Select Case Me.Type.Value
    Case 1, 3
        Select Case Me.Ownership
            Case 2, 3, 4, 6 
                Me.HousesToRent.Visible = True
                Me.HousesForSale.Visible = False
                Me.ApartmentToRent.Visible = False
                Me.ApartmentForSale.Visible = False
                Me.OfficeAndWarehouse.Visible = False
                Me.PlotForSale.Visible = False            
        End Select
End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Me.Type.Value = 1 And Me.Ownership = 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 6
```

evaluates to

```
(Me.Type.Value = 1 And Me.Ownership = 2) Or 3 Or 4 Or 6
```

Everything <> 0 is always `True`, so your whole `If` statement is always `True`.

You want:

```
Me.Type.Value = 1 And (Me.Ownership = 2 Or Me.Ownership = 3 Or Me.Ownership = 4 Or Me.Ownership = 6)
```